# Adding Relation in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created 2 tables on my rails app: `Contact` and `Category` using the ff:

`rails g controller Contact name email`

`rails g model Category title`

Both were already migrated. As you can see there are no relation on this two. My question is how do I make a relation so that on Contact model there will be `category_id` field?

Is there a rails command for that? or some migration command that I can run?

UPDATES:

I tried to run this but I got this errors below upon `rails db:migrate`:

```
rails aborted!
SyntaxError: /home/jojo/Desktop/contacthub/db/migrate/20200108110024_create_contacts.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting end
      t.string :email,
               ^
/home/jojo/Desktop/contacthub/db/migrate/20200108110024_create_contacts.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting end
      t.string :phone,
               ^
/home/jojo/Desktop/contacthub/db/migrate/20200108110024_create_contacts.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting end
      t.string :address,
               ^
/home/jojo/Desktop/contacthub/db/migrate/20200108110024_create_contacts.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting end
      t.string :state,
               ^
/home/jojo/Desktop/contacthub/db/migrate/20200108110024_create_contacts.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting end
      t.text :note
             ^
/home/jojo/Desktop/contacthub/db/migrate/20200108110024_create_contacts.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:986:in `load_migration'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:982:in `migration'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:977:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1350:in `use_transaction?'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1342:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1291:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1263:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `each'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `migrate_without_lock'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `block in migrate'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1363:in `with_advisory_lock'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `migrate'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/jojo/Desktop/contacthub/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/home/jojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jojo/Desktop/contacthub/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/jojo/Desktop/contacthub/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here's the migration file:

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name,
      t.string :email,
      t.string :mobile,
      t.string :phone,
      t.string :country,
      t.string :address,
      t.string :city,
      t.string :state,
      t.string :zip,
      t.text :note
      t.references :category, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: While generating you can use `references` keyword. `rails g model Contact name email category:references`

Comment: on my contact model `has_many :categories`, and on my category mode: `belongs_to :contact` is this right?

Comment: It means that category table references contact table. So you change the model generation for Category to this `rails g model Category title contact:references`. It will add a contact_id column to contact table

Comment: Did not work see my updates above.

Comment: @JoanBuan You don't need commas in the migration between lines. ie not needed after `t.string :name` and all the others

Answer (score 0):

If you've already run the migrations for Contact and Category; create a migration to add the reference. `rails g migration AddCategoryToContacts`

```
add_reference :contacts, :category, foreign_key: true, null: false
add_index :contacts, :category_id
```

If you want to rollback, you could then just edit the migration and add

```
create_table :contacts do |t|
  t.references :category, foreign_key: true, null: false, index: true
  ...
end
```

Comment: `index: true` is not needed to mention, by [default it is `true`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d700456cb72bd38dcf6f540a3b7f6593879b456f/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L123)

Comment: on my contact model `has_many :categories`, and on my category mode: `belongs_to :contact` is this right?

Comment: @JoanBuan You don't need commas in the migration between lines. ie not needed after `t.string :name` and all the others

Comment: @ArupRakshit ya, i just like to be extra verbose sometimes :P

Answer (score 0):

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :mobile
      t.string :phone
      t.string :country
      t.string :address
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :zip
      t.text :note
      t.references :category, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

`t.string :name` is an expression that calls the method `string` on the block argument `t`. Expressions in Ruby are terminated by a line end or by semicolumns. Placing a comma at the end of an expression will result in a syntax error.

I think you may have confused this with a hash which uses commas to deliminate key value pairs:

```
numbers = { 
  one: "eins", 
  two: "zwei", 
  three: "drei" 
}
```